# Add additional custom values on top of default ag-grid column set filter

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

What is the easiest way to add additional custom values on top of the default values in ag-grid's 'Set' filter? My use case is that I have a table where the data is occasionally changing and values present in a particular column come and go, however if a user is filtered on a particular value then I want to save that selection to be applied in the future if that data is present again.

A real world example is a table showing a Job Scheduler where status is in a set of [RUNNING, SUCCESS, ERROR]. Maybe the user has a filter on RUNNING, however momentarily if there are no jobs running then the default behavior is to not show RUNNING as an option.

I know I probable need to override filterValueGetter, however I'd like to not re-implement the whole Set behavior. Ideally I would keep my own list of selected values from the user and wrap the default behavior to merge user selected values with the values present in the data.